# Fail to start NET.Tcp Port Service

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-services

I can't start the following windows services on my Win 7 machine. When I try to start the service of Net.Tcp Port Sharing service, I got the error:

> The Service on local computer started and then stopped ,Some services stop automatically if there are not in use by other services or programs

[image: nettcp]

So I modified the SMSvcHost.exe.config file by the [help.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asiatech/archive/2012/07/16/modifying-smsvchost-exe-config-for-wcf-some-common-mistakes.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage)
I changed two files `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\SMSvcHost.exe.config` and `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\SMSvcHost.exe.config`

The configuration file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- The configuration file for SMSvcHost.exe -->
<configuration>
   <runtime>
    <gcConcurrent enabled="false" />
  </runtime>
 <system.serviceModel>
    <!-- SMSvcHost ETW traces are redirected by default to an etwProviderId different from WCF's default. 
         To trace to the default provider, remove the etwProviderId attribute below. -->
    <diagnostics performanceCounters="Off" etwProviderId="{f18839f5-27ff-4e66-bd2d-639b768cf18b}"/>
</system.serviceModel>
<!-- Below are some sample config settings: -->   
<system.serviceModel.activation>
    <net.tcp listenBacklog="10" maxPendingConnections="100" maxPendingAccepts="10" receiveTimeout="00:00:10" teredoEnabled="false">
        <allowAccounts>
            // LocalSystem account
            <add securityIdentifier="S-1-5-18"/>

            // LocalService account
            <add securityIdentifier="S-1-5-19"/>

            // Administrators account
            <add securityIdentifier="S-1-5-20"/>

            // Network Service account
            <add securityIdentifier="S-1-5-32-544" />

            // IIS_IUSRS account (Vista only)
            <add securityIdentifier="S-1-5-32-568"/>
        </allowAccounts>
    </net.tcp>
    <net.pipe maxPendingConnections="100" maxPendingAccepts="10" receiveTimeout="00:00:10">
        <allowAccounts>
            // LocalSystem account
            <add securityIdentifier="S-1-5-18"/>

            // LocalService account
            <add securityIdentifier="S-1-5-19"/>

            // Administrators account
            <add securityIdentifier="S-1-5-20"/>

            // Network Service account
            <add securityIdentifier="S-1-5-32-544" />

            // IIS_IUSRS account (Vista only)
            <add securityIdentifier="S-1-5-32-568"/>
        </allowAccounts>
    </net.pipe>
    <diagnostics performanceCountersEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel.activation>
```

Unfortunately the modification will ***not*** take effect even I restart the desktop machine.. I am sure that sure SMSvcHost.exe does not exist in Task Manager.

Comment: Why do you feel they need to be started?  What's the actual problem you're trying to solve by enabling/starting them?

Comment: Are there any events for the failed start?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007t, I have an application which has many windows services. These windows service are upon on the Net.Tcp services. I need to start these Net.Tcp services first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under some help, I got the solution. 
There are two errors.

- The configuration contains invalid values. Ex: `// LocalService account`. It should be `<!-- LocalService account  -->`.
- Installed a NetFxRepairTool from [here.](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30135)

The main problem is that during install .net framework, something is missing.